# Can I revert Mail.app to handle notifications in the pre-10.9.2 way?

Tags: macos, mail.app, notifications

After updating to the latest Mavericks version (10.9.2), the behaviour of the new mail notifications changed. Before, if I clicked on the notification, the main Mail.app window would open and show the message in the thread preview pane. After the update, the message is opened into it's own window (same as double-clicking the message in the main window), which is not what I want.

Is there a setting somewhere to restore the previous behaviour?

Comment: Darn you! Since I noticed this behavior I really want the old behavior back! ;)

Comment: It's the same when you use Growl/GrowlMail. Maybe Apple has changed that to act the same way it acts on iPhone/iPad. I somewhere have read (sry can't remember where) that it is Possible to an Applescript to a GrowlNotification so it should kinda be possible to bring this Feature back. Maybe there is someone out there who is able to write such a Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not work out of the box. But there is a nice and free plugin called [Herald](http://erikhinterbichler.com/apps/herald/) which gives you this exact feature back, and many more on top.

(See Version 4.0.8 (Mac OS X 10.9) by clicking on "Old Versions").

Please close your Mail.app before installing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and state that this isn't coded in the Mail app and that you'll need to hack the mail program (hard but not impossible) to change this. It's not looking like there are any hidden defaults you can set to revert this behavior.